# PHPExel LineChart: How can I display empty cell as a gap and not as 0 value

Tags: phpexcel, linechart

I would like to generate a LineChart with PHPExcel, where empty cells are not displayed as 0 values but displayed as a gap.
In my code I tried in the constructor of PHPExcelChart a lot of different values for the argument "displayBlanksAs", such like ' ' or DISPLAY_BLANKS_AS_GAP or 'X' or NULL, etc. But nothing worked. The empty cell is always displayed as 0 not as a gap.

Is there anyone, who has an idea?Many thanks in advance!
Here my PHP-Code:

```
<?php
...
$dataSeriesValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$58:$Q$58', NULL, 14),);
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,      // plotType
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED,    // plotGrouping
range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
NULL,                               // plotLabel
NULL,                               // plotCategory
$dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues);
//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
//  Create the Chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
'chart1',       // name
NULL,           // title
NULL,       // legend
$plotArea,      // plotArea
true,           // plotVisibleOnly
DISPLAY_BLANKS_AS_GAP,  // displayBlanksAs => here I tried ' ',NULL,'X', etc.,  empty cells are always displayed as 0, not as a gap
NULL,           // xAxisLabel
NULL        // yAxisLabel
);  
//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('R58');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('X58');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->addChart($chart);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

I had to change in the constructor of PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries the **plotGrouping** - parameter from GROUPING_STACKED to **GROUPING_STANDARD**:

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,      // plotType
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,    // plotGrouping
range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
NULL,                               // plotLabel
NULL,                               // plotCategory
$dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues);
```

Then the empty cells are displayed as gaps.